# Extend Session Timeout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to extend the session timeout in my .net mvc application.

I am doing a .get to an action result. It seems to work properly.
Just wanted to confirm that a GET or POST would do the same thing in terms of extending the session timeout.

Comment: Any page request will extend the session (GET, POST, PUT).

Answer (score 0):

```
<sessionState customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" mode="InProc" timeout="1500">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

give this in web.config file in your solution..timeout can be changed as per your requirement.